# iOS Camera Roll and Photo Stream workflow

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, photos, photo-stream, camera

When I take a photo on my iPhone it is added to both the Camera Roll and Photo Stream.  I can then upload the photo into "permanent" storage in Mac iPhoto either from Photo Stream or Camera Roll (during a sync).

1. Is there any difference in the photo stored in Camera Roll or Photo Stream?
2. Photo Stream automatically reduces the resolution when it transfers a photo to an iOS device.  Does this down resolution process only apply to photos transferred to a different iOS device, i.e. a photo taken on the iPhone is full resolution on the original iPhone but would be down sampled if Photo Stream transferred it to a different iPhone?
3. Is there any easy way to delete multiple photos from Camera Roll and Photo Stream on an iOS device?  One at a time isn't exactly practical for the hundreds of photos I might take on a long trip.

Comment: You have three questions here, could you pop them into individual questions, well two seperate ones should sufice

Answer (score 4):

1. A photo stored in the Camera Roll is permanently stored on your device (until you delete it). Only 1,000 photos are saved in the Photo Stream on an iOS device, so if enough photos are uploaded to your Photo Stream the old ones will be purged. (But a Mac or PC will save all of the photos in your Photo Stream by default.)
2. [According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4486), the downscaling does only apply on iOS devices — if you have Photo Stream set up on your computer, those photos will be full-resolution.

   > On your Mac or PC, your photos are downloaded and stored in full resolution. On your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV, your Photo Stream photos are delivered in a device-optimized resolution that speeds downloads and saves storage space.
3. Yes — to delete multiple photos, just tap the action button in the upper right corner, select some photos, and tap the Delete button.

   [image]
   [image]